# Android :- Separate class for handling views clicks etc;

Tags: java, android, android-layout, oop

I am new to development field. I am developing android application where in my activity_main layout I have many different items. On clicking one of the button the top layout is replaced with a new layout.

Now instead of defining the new layouts buttons, textview etc in my main class , I want to have a separate class which can initialize my buttons etc, and also in that class I can declare onClickListners.

In my main Activity I want:-

```
public void onCreate(){

button bb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
View CurrentContentView= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);
bb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 new MyNewViewInit(CurrentContentView);
            }
        });


}
```

In my MyNewViewInit() class :-

```
 public class MyNewViewInit{

    ImageButton backbutton;
    ChipsMultiAutoCompleteTextview search;
    ImageButton searchclear;
    ImageButton modeTime;
    ImageButton  modeTag;
    TextView modeTimeTxt;
    TextView modeTagTxt;
    ScrollView mainScroll;
    ScrollView selectedScroll;

    public MyNewViewInit(View v){
        backbutton = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
        search = (ChipsMultiAutoCompleteTextview)v.findViewById(R.id.search);
        searchclear = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.searchclear);
        modeTime = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.modeTime);
        modeTag = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.modeTag);
        modeTimeTxt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.modeTimeTxt);
        modeTagTxt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.modeTagTxt);
        mainScroll = (ScrollView)v.findViewById(R.id.HAT1);
        selectedScroll = (ScrollView)v.findViewById(R.id.HAT2);
        tag = new OtherHelper().arrayread();
        mainHashTag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        selectedHashTag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        clickListners();


    }

public void clickListners(){

        backbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        searchclear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        modeTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });

        modeTimeTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        modeTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        modeTagTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });


    }

}
```

So when I try using this code the onclicklistners are not working.

What is the best way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to implement an Interface between your Activity class and ViewInit class

Comment: @PsyGik can you please help me with writing a sample interface. I searched for interface online but was not able to implement an interface in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Write an Interface in your class,

```
    class MyNewViewInit{

    public interface ClickListenerInterface{
        void onCLickSomething(Something something);
    }

    ClickListenerInterface mClickListener;
    ...
     public MyNewViewInit(View v,ClickListenerInterface clickListener){
         mClickListener = clickListener;
         ...
    }

    public void clickListners(){
        ...
        backbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(mClickListener!=null){
                    mClickListener.onCLickSomething(v);
                    }else{
                    //throw an error that activity should implement ClickListenerInterface
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    }
```

In your Activity,

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements ClickListenerInterface{
    public void onCreate(){
        bb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 new MyNewViewInit(CurrentContentView,this);
                 //if using Android Studio, then use the context menu to implement the                     interface
            }
        });
    }

    void onCLickSomething(Something something){
        //do something with something
    }
}
```

Comment: But in this way I need to declare actual onclick part in main activity class only

Answer (score 0):

You can try do a abstract class extends Activity, like :

```
public abstract class MyInitActivity extends Activity
{
    EditText  editText;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID)
    {
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}
```

and in your main activity you can extend your abstract class, like :

```
public class MainActivity extends MyInitActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    /*********** Listener ************/
    public void onButtonClick(View v)
    {
        textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

you can also implement onClick() in the abstract class

i don't know if its a good practice , i prefer do the methods with view arguments and set this methods in the layout.xml file .

Answer (score 0):

I had use this in one of code

STEP 1
Declare button in layout(XML file)

STEP 2
Declare all ur button like this--

```
Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
Button btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
```

............so on
STEP 3

implement View.OnClickListener

Now after step 2 do this

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

.
.
.
same way for all

STEP 4:
 Use switch case inside Onclick

```
public void OnClick(View v)
{
case:R.id.btn1{
//ur command similarly use multiple case stmt for many button
}

}
```